# How to evaluate an arbitrary mathematical expression

Tags: programming-languages, semantics

For Instance, if I allowed the user to pass in expressions like "35 + 2 * 5" as strings, how would I go about writing such a program?
Also, what topics does this question fall under?

Comment: I suggest you look up "parsing". The way we usually do it these days is in two conceptual phases (although it's arguably overkill for a desk calculator): lexical analysis breaks the string into tokens (the number 35, the plus symbol, etc), and syntax analysis discovers the structure (e.g. multiplication binds more tightly than addition).

Comment: If I were to take a course on compilers, will this be covered there?

Comment: Yes, it will. You might also consider hanging out in [langdev.SE].

Answer (score 2):

Well, this is a common problem, that is used similarly for making a programming language. I do not know exactly what branch is belongs to, my guess would be something similar to computational linguistics, but this is of course, a simpler case I believe.

Anyways, I would probably go ahead and make a token system and a parser. So you make a program, maybe something along the lines of a parse tree. All leafs, except for the bottom ones are operators like +, -, *, /, and only the bottom leafs of the tree is the numbers. This gives a systematic way to figure out how to want to evaluate the expression, by using some conversion etc.

Its not entirely simple, I saw something similar being done when a guy on youtube tried to make a programming language using C#. I can give you a link if you are interested?

Comment: Yes, I would love a link to the video.

Comment: This guy right here: https://www.youtube.com/live/wgHIkdUQbp0?si=U63UDNSdXMlsACO8. I wish I had time to watch it all, but I never had time for it :( Anyways, wish you luck! :D

Comment: Thank you very much.